# Getting error when trying to use New-JobSchedule with the -Argumentlist

Tags: powershell

Hei

I'm very new on PowerShell, InFact i started learning it like a 3 weeks ago.

I'm trying to make a script block run automatically with New-jobSchedule with passing an argument list to the script block with -argumentlist

the command looks like this

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name "Backup" -Trigger $jobTrigger -ScheduledJobOption $joboption -ScriptBlock @jobs -ArgumentList $Target $Destination $FilePW $email
```

The script block registers only the first argument which is $Target, but i get an error message on the second one

(assuming throwing a path)

```
Register-ScheduledJob : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'C:\Users\user\Documents'.
```

i tried adjusting the parameters in the script block in many ways with and without positioning, but that didn't help. the original param looked like this

```
param([string]$Target = (Read-Host "Enter the source" ) ,
[string]$Destination = (Read-Host "Enter the dist"),
[string]$FilePW = (Read-Host "enter ps (optional)"),
[string]$email = (Read-Host "Enter your email if you want the reports (Optional)"))
```

any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `-ArgumentList $Target $Destination $FilePW $email` -> `-ArgumentList $Target,$Destination,$FilePW,$email`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you so much. You saved the day, but i ran into another problem. Some of the arguments are optional in the script block, and if i dont  fill the inputs ( arguments) in the jobscheduler, i get this error `Register-ScheduledJob : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ArgumentList'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the      
command again.` any ideas how to fix this ? appreciate your help